# How do I forward a POST request to a third party server using Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-security, request, response, forward

I’m using Spring version 4.1.5.RELEASE and Spring Security 3.2.5.RELEASE.  How do I forward a POST request to a third party server when all I have available to me are the HttpServletRequest request and HttpServletResponse response objects?

Note I don’t want to do a redirect because that causes the POST parameters to get lost and I don’t want to append the POST params to the query string, thus changing my request from a POST to a GET.

Comment: You could use RestTemplate. Are you sure you need to do on server, and can't do in browser with form action?

Comment: One of the parameters I want to forward on is a password.  I'm slightly weary of including a "<input type='hidden' name='password' value='opensaysme' />" on a browser form.

Answer (score 0):

One of my past projects involved something like a proxy server/middleware, and we had this requirement too.

This straightforward communication involved basically a copy and paste of the original request parameters and headers, and a subsequent POST Request to the final target.

Comment: Hi, I'm not understanding what you're desciribng here.  Can you include the code for what you're describing in your answer?